# Will I get ConcurrentModificationException if I add objects to a Queue as I'm going through it?

Tags: java, collections, queue, concurrentmodification

I wasn't sure how to form the question..

Basically I have this code:

```
java.util.Queue myQueue;

...

myQueue.stream().filter(particle -> particle instanceof ParticleDigging).forEach(particle -> {
     myQueue.add(new ParticleSmoke());
});
```

Now what I want to know is if it would throw a ConcurrentModificationException at some point.

Can it even throw the exception with .stream()?

Comment: Dunno, but I wouldn't try to alter a collection while iterating it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a ConcurrentLinkedQueue implementation for your queue.
If you look at the java docs they do not throw a concurrentModificationException because internally it uses an iterator.

[ConcurrentLinkedQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html)

```
Queue<Particle> myQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
```

if you convert to a stream then stream makes a spliterator which has the same effect:

```
default Stream<E> stream() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator(), false);
    }
```